# Order of executing roles, tasks, pre_tasks, post_task. Can tasks be defined in playbook?

Tags: ansible, task

In playbook we can define `roles`, `pre_tasks`, `post_tasks`.
Can we also define `tasks`  ?
And second question is about order of executing these things. I know that order is following: `pre_tasks -> roles -> post_tasks`.
However, when `tasks` are executed?

Answer (score 23):

Here it is: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html?#using-roles

1. Any pre_tasks defined in the play.
2. Any handlers triggered so far will be run.
3. Each role listed in roles will execute in turn.
4. Any role dependencies defined in the roles meta/main.yml will be run first, subject to tag filtering and conditionals.
5. Any tasks defined in the play.
6. Any handlers triggered so far will be run.
7. Any post_tasks defined in the play.
8. Any handlers triggered so far will be run.

Comment: Is it defined order from up to down ?

Comment: Err... `pre_tasks` first.

Comment: I understand "Any tasks", but in what order?

Comment: I added ordering to clarify.